# How to Delete (or Add) objects inside an Array that are part of a Firebase Firestore Cloud document?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Collection (Patients) in Firestore with several documents (Each Patient), each one with an auto generated ID, in my web app im showing one specific document which i got from its ID using the ActivatedRoute from angular router.

In my service i can access one individual "Patient" by id, using the following code:

```js
export class FirebaseService {
  private patientCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Ipatients>;

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.patientCollection = afs.collection<Ipatients>("Patient", (ref) =>
      ref.orderBy("Name")
    );
  }

 public getOnePatient(id: Ipatients): Observable<Ipatients> {
    return this.afs.doc<Ipatients>(`Patient/${id}`).valueChanges();
  }
```

This is my component.ts where i request the single patient (by id) inside ngOnInit

```js
constructor(
    private fbservice: FirebaseService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
      console.log(params["id"]);
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const idPatient = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
    this.fbpatient$ = this.fbservice.getOnePatient(idPatient);
  }
```

In the HTML i only render part of the Patient information, the part i render is the Array inside de document called sessions, and **those are the sessions that i want the user to interact with**, so i loop through the sessions array inside my Patient and show each object inside with ngFor

[Image showing the Patient structure in Firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvWPi.jpg)

This is an example of a Patient data:

```js
 fbpatient: Ipatients = 
    {
      id: "asdSDWESHGawhadah",
      Nombre: "John",
      Apellido: "Doe",
      Edad: "30",
      Telefono: "098849625",
      Mutualista: "SMI",
      Sesiones: [         // THIS IS THE ARRAY I WANT TO C.R.U.D 
        {
          nombre: "Sesion1",
          ordenesEntregadas: 1,
          fechaSesion: new Date(2019, 11, 24),
          asistencia: "Asistio",
          conAviso: null,
          datosCompletos: true,
        },
        {
          nombre: "Sesion2",
          ordenesEntregadas: 1,
          fechaSesion: new Date(2019, 11, 24),
          asistencia: "Asistio",
          conAviso: null,
          datosCompletos: true,
        },
      ],
    }
```

My question is how do i Delete (or add) "sessions" inside my patient, what code do i need on my service? I couldnt find any example of this case, only CRUD of the whole document